# Cannot create specified Microsoft outlook 2016 rule

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, rules

i have some big difficult with create rule. I want that some messages, that comes only to group, attention, only to group  (when in TO field is this specified group and nothing else) and this group is not in cc field, move to specified folder.

When i'm using sent to specified people or public group, this is not working for me. if in cc box is this, my group, also it's coming in my folder. i want only, when this group is in TO field only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a frequently requested feature. But unfortunately, this can't be done with Outlook rules without using VBA. For some (known only to Microsoft) reason, Outlook rules can only differentiate To/CC for your personal email address =(